# how to authenticate password in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I want to authenticate password in devise before changing password:

```
def admin_update_password
    admin = Admin.find(current_admin.id)
    @result = false
    @error_msg = Hash.new
    #update admin password
    password_old = params[:admin][:password_old]
    password_new = params[:admin][:password_new]
    password_new_confirmation = params[:admin][:password_new_confirmation]
    unless password_old.blank? && password_new.blank? && password_new_confirmation.blank?
      if password_new == password_new_confirmation 
        if admin.authenticate(password_old)
          #generate new password for admin accroding to given from front-end
          admin.update_attribute(:encrypted_password, BCrypt::Password.create(password_new))
          @result = true
        else
          @error_msg[:error_password] = "old password error"
        end
      else
        @error_msg[:old_password] = "new password and old password is not same"
      end
    else
      @error_msg[:is_nil] = "old password, new password and password confirmation can not be blank"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render nothing: true }
      format.js { render partial: 'shared/op_result' }
    end
  end
```

i googled and found that devise also use BCrypt gem to encrypt password.
so, i added `BCrypt` gem in my project too.
and, i add `has_secure_password` to my model that allow me to use `if admin.authenticate(password_old)` this method to authenticate the password is correct or not.

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

after i done above all, i got an error

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
```

what's more, after add `has_secure_password` to model, i can't `create` model.it will be ok only if i comment `has_secure_password`

Comment: Please update your question, with the error that you get or a traceback. Anything that helps orthers to pinpoint your mistake without having to try and run this code snippet themselves.

Comment: Also give us an idea of what you're tried to do to get it working. What you googled and why that was not satisfactory to you. What you expect to see happening and what you observe instead.

Comment: i just edited it again......

Comment: What is needed here is enough of the stack trace to tell where the error occurred.  Which line of which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a password is correct you can use:

```
admin.valid_password?(password_old)
```

which will return a Boolean value.

Comment: Could you better contextualize in which part of the code your solution does apply?